# Giving a Priority to the Last Occuring Event within a Time Period

Tags: jquery

I have a function where I would like the last occurrence of an event to override the earlier ones. In the following example, I would like for any keypress event that happens within the 2 seconds period to restart the timing.

```
$("#myTextArea").keyup(function () {
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('form').submit();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout` to stop the timer. Try this:

```
var timer;
$("#myTextArea").keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('form').submit();
    }, 2000);
});
```

From a user experience point of view, I would find this behaviour both annoying and confusing. A form should only be submit when I've specifically performed an action to do so.